# Masonry - animate percentage item width with jQuery - 80% width not working

Tags: jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

Currently working on a project with Masonry and found an example code and i want width to 80% instead of 60% (with all items wrapping around nicely without spaces) but not working.

See code the code - http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/JFpIB

I just want to change the width on "line 52" (on the CSS column) to "80%", and I want all the boxes to wrap around perfectly without any space - For example when you click 3rd box, it expands and leaves a space (unlike when it is set to "60%")?

```
/* Line 52 - need to change to 80% */
.item.is-expanded {
width: 60%;
height: 120px;
}
```

Any clue why this is happening and what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/nxaBE

Looks like there was a slight mistake with the code. I had an extra bit of CSS that was overwriting line 52. This should now be fixed.

Comment: Thanks Desandro, the 4th and 5th boxes still not wrapping around when you click on the 3rd box. being stirring at this all day.